# jQuery - Can't seem to .live() bind to a label element. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, bind, live

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="more-items">
   <li><label class="button">hi</label></li>
   <li><label class="button">hi</label></li>
   <li><label class="button">hi</label></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('ul#more-items label.button').live('click', function()
{
   alert(1);
});
```

Clicking on the labels doesn't cause the alert() to fire. The .live() bind seems to have no affect on the label element...

If I change it to use .click() or even .bind(), it works perfectly.
Is there any reason why .live() isn't working? Is there a way to fix this?

The reason I'm using .live() is because `ul#more-items` will be readded to the page multiple times and I don't want to have to fire off a function each time that happens to rebind the click.

Comment: You really can't expect **anything** to work if you share the same "id" value between multiple elements.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery's `live()` method relies on event bubbling (all the way up to the root node) to work.

If there's any code that will stop the bubbling of the event on either the `label` or any of its ancestors, `live()` will not work.

Any chance that the `label` or one of its ancestors has a handler with either of the following?

```
return false;
```

or

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

If so, `live()` will fail.

---

**Relevant jQuery docs:**

- `.live()` - http://api.jquery.com/live/
- `.stopPropagation()` - [http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/](http://api.jquery.com/http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: I just stumbled upon this problem. My labels have a plugin binded to them that returns false. The reason for this is the .click() function (binded to the label) fires twice unless false is returned. See: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/af789262532a4c68

Comment: That will do it. The `return false;` causes the bubbling to halt, so the handler, which is at the root of the DOM tree, never gets notified to fire. I assume the elements are added dynamically. If so, you should be able to use `bind` instead of `live` when you create the elements. Then there's no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Element ids must be unique. Your stament "The reason I'm using .live() is because ul#more-items will be readded to the page multiple times.. " tells me that you will have multiple of these:

```
<ul id="more-items"> 
  <!--Stuff-->
</ul>
<ul id="more-items"> 
  <!--Stuff-->
</ul>
```

This would be invalid HTML as the ID more-items exists twice.

Comment: Forgot I was readding that UL multiple times when I was writing the HTML >.< Changed it to class now. Doesn't fix the .live() problem, though.

Comment: Did you change the selector too? `ul.more-items label.button` (change "#" to ".")

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('label.button').live('click', function()
{
   alert(1);
});
```

or

```
$('ul#more-items').delegate('label.button','click', function()
{
   alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok, but your alert should be alert("1");

or:

var 1="1";

alert(1);

Comment: alert(1) is valid.  to test type javascript:alert(1) in your address bar.  you will see that it properly alerts the number 1.

Comment: @Reigel, could I be wrong ? :(  [ @John Hartsock, humm... tks for the head's up :) ]

Comment: @Zuul - Well, I'm guessing you should.. ;) don't overuse the brain... ;) sleep well.. ;)

Comment: @Reigel, It's 4AM here, yesterday was an holly-day, but I've been working since 10AM, that makes 18hours of codding on a supposed quiet day :) (well... gonna sleep) ps: catch you tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It may work

Change:

```
$('ul#more-items label.button').live('click', function() 
{ 
   alert(1); 
});
```

To This:

```
$('ul#more-items label.button').unbind('click').live('click', function() 
{ 
   alert(1); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me. What version of jquery are you using? Are you defining the javascript in a $(document).ready function?

Comment: Yeah, I've got my code in the $(document).ready function. I'm using: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js